# Chrome extension to set password

Tags: chrome

Is there any Chrome extension which give you this ability to set password for Chrome? Such that just by entering the password you have access to that browser?

Comment: If you enter the password incorrectly do you want the browser to be non-functional or just limited functionality (ie won't remember/suggest website passwords)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ChromePW](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromepw/oeiimoikalhhgfhfkfhngehekefpiaag).

- asks for a password when you open Chrome
- you can lock it manually by right clicking and clicking *ChromePW*
- if you press anything inside the Chrome window while the password box is open, then Chrome automatically closes
- if the password is wrong more than a user-defined limit, Chrome will automatically close
- security mode: if you try to open *any* other program (such as Task Manager), Chrome will automatically close (so it can't be bypassed; *optional*)

The settings you can change:

[image]

The password box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ChromePW](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromepw/oeiimoikalhhgfhfkfhngehekefpiaag)

[Either way you can also create multiple profiles in chrome if you dont want other users to know about the data in you account.](http://techiegenie.blogspot.in/2013/09/creating-guest-account-in-googlechrome.html) and also use ChromePW there again. So it would be just like having multiple accounts in your PC and asking each user to signin using his password.